# logout with api rest drupal not workign with ionic3!

Tags: javascript

hi i try to logout from drupal8 using api rest but i recieve this Forbidden 403
y code is look like this :

```
 deConnecter(){



   let apiloginUrl = 'http://domaine.com/user/logout?_format=json';
   let headers = new Headers();
   headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   headers.append('X-CSRF-Token',localStorage.getItem('loggedin_token') );
   this.http.post(apiloginUrl,{headers: headers})
       .subscribe(data => {

        this.connection = undefined;
        localStorage.removeItem('loggedin_token')
        this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);
        console.log(data);

       }, error => {
         console.log("Access Denied");
       });
```

}

Comment: Logout is a `POST` resource

Comment: sorry, i tried the both of them (get and post) but it still return Forbidden 403

Comment: with get methodei get this :  {"message":"The \u0022user\u0022 parameter was not converted for the path \u0022\/user\/{user}\u0022 (route name: \u0022rest.entity.user.GET.json\u0022)"}